# React not rendering component into page

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I've searched existing solutions on here but nothing seems to answer my question, so here is my issue.

I've set up a new Laravel project using react, and have just put together a basic Dashboard page, which currently is just meant to render a component called PageHeader with the title 'Dashboard' on it. However, the div is not being populated by this content.

Here is my setup:

app.js (using react-router 3.2.0):

```
require('./bootstrap');

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { hashHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router';

import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/home" component={Dashboard} />
    </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The component `Dashboard`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PageHeader from './../PageHeader';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <PageHeader title="Dashboard" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

The component `PageHeader`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class PageHeader extends Component {
    render() {

        const { title } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <h1>{ title }</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My `web.php` file (I basically just use a wildcard as I am using the same blade file to render all pages):

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/{any}', function () {
        return view('page');
    })->where('any', '.*');
});
```

The blade file rendering the main content:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        @if (session('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        <div id="app"></div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

When I load the page, it throws no errors, but the `app` div element is always blank - I am wondering if it is because the page is loading too late for the actual content to render in?

I'm unsure why this is happening as I have recently finished a project very similar to this with the same components and modules, with no problems - so if anyone can shed some light on this I'd be grateful.

EDIT:

I am using webpack mix to transpile my css / js by the way if this helps.

Comment: Is it because render doesn't return anything in the app component?

Comment: Yes that's the problem - but I don't understand why since there's no errors and it's set up the same way as my previous projects which did work.

Comment: are you still having this problem? I just fixed a very similar problem using the Laravel - React stack but I was using React Router 4.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar problem and the hangup was something to do with my react router setup. Try consolidating your "menu html" so that it is in the same render call as your initial react router setup.

Something like this. (not 100% sure here because I was using react router 4)

```
require('./bootstrap');

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { hashHistory, Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';

import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
            <div>
                <Link to='/home'>Dashboard</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Route path="/home" component={Dashboard} />
    </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Then modify your dashboard so that it just loads the props.children into that div

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Again sorry for not running the code myself but I didn't want to switch around to react router 3. Bottom line is try to load your "menu html code" along with your initial react router render and also tie all your sub components somehow into that app.js. If youre still having trouble after that get rid of your react router code and just load a basic text react module to troubleshoot it down to your react router code.